# Return non-associated array using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

The following will return `array('a'=>123,'b'=>'abc','c'=>null)`

```
$sql='SELECT a,b,c FROM myTable WHERE id=123';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$rs= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Is it possible to return `array(123,'abc',null)` without doing something like `array($rs['a'],$rs['b'],$rs['c'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `PDO::FETCH_NUM`

```
$sql='SELECT a,b,c FROM myTable WHERE id=123';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$rs= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rs = array_values($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Also

> PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned
>   in your result set, starting at column 0